# successfully logged in and redirect to the successful page. Nevertheless, I can't get the authenticated user within the successful page in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

For login, I submitted the right credentials but in the controller after checking the user that provided user information from the database. But in the successful page user info is not provided. **Asking for help from experts.** Here I am sharing some codes for better understanding.
**Controller:**

```
     ` public function authenticate(Request $request):RedirectResponse
   { $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

           if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
       $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    return redirect()->route("login")->withSuccess('Oppes! You have entered invalid credentials);
```

}`
**config/auth:**

```
'defaults' => [
'guard' => 'web',
'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'redirectTo'=> 'dashboard',  //checked it doing comment and uncomment
    'provider' => 'users',
 ],
],
'providers' => [
 'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
 ],
],
'passwords' => [
 'users' => [
    'provider' => 'users',
    'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
    'expire' => 60,
    'throttle' => 60,
 ],
],
'password_timeout' => 10800,
```

**In web file:**

```
    Route::get('/login',[Authenticationcontroller::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::post('/authenticate', [Authenticationcontroller::class, 'authenticate'])- 
      >name('authenticate');
```

**In User Model:**

```
 public $incrementing = false;
 protected $table = 'users';
 protected $guard = 'web';
 protected $primarykey = 'User_ID';
 protected $keyType = 'string';
 protected $fillable = ['First_Name','Last_Name', rest of the column ];
 protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];
```

**Notes:**

**In .env file:**  after using SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost , showed the massage "419 page expired".

**In Dashboard:** After using  {{  dd(auth()->user())}} , It return null but if I use dd(auth()->user()) in controller it return full user information.

**In routeService provider:** change the HOME;that was "public const HOME = '/home';"  instead of "public const HOME =  'route("dashboard")';"

**For further queries please do comments.**

Comment: Why you regenerate session on success attempt case?

Comment: @Maksim check this- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication